# Matplotlib custom marker/symbols

Tags: python, matplotlib, symbols

I run the 41st script in jupyter notebook it shows:

```
TypeError                                
 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a8519e2b712a> in <module>
     24 
     25 for i, mi in enumerate(markers):
---> 26     plt.plot(x[i], y[i], "b", alpha=0.5, marker=getRandomMarker(), markersize=randint(16,26,1))
     27     plt.plot(x[i], y[i]+50, "m", alpha=0.5, marker=getMarker(i), markersize=randint(16,26,1))
     28     # Let's see if their "center" is located where we expect them to be...

<ipython-input-4-a8519e2b712a> in getRandomMarker()
     17 
     18 def getRandomMarker():
---> 19     return "$"+markers[randint(0,len(markers),1)]+"$"
     20 
     21 def getMarker(i):
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

However, this scripts work very well in idle, why Notebook has such bugs?

Comment: Try to understand the error. It says that you cannot use an a scalar array when it does not contain an integer. So `randint(0,len(markers),1)` returns an array of a different dtype. You will need to convert it to an integer number.

Comment: Try `markers[int(randint(0,len(markers),1))]`